# How to assign different row's value to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a column, 'C_End', to a DataFrame in Pandas that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,123,123,456,456,789],
                   'C_ID':[8,10,35,36,40,7],
                   'C_Type':['New','Renew','Renew','New','Term','New'],
                   'Rank':[1,2,3,1,2,1]})
```

The new column needs to be the next 'C_Type' for each ID based on 'Rank', resulting in a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    ID  C_ID C_Type Rank  C_End  
0  123     8    New    1  Renew
1  123    10  Renew    2  Renew
2  123    35  Renew    3   None
3  456    36    New    1   Term
4  456    40   Term    2   None
5  789     7    New    1   None
```

Essentially, I want to find the row where ID = ID and Rank = Rank+1 and assign C_Type to new column C_End. I've tried creating a function and using Apply (below), but that took forever and eventually gave me an error. I'm still new to Pandas and Python in general, but I feel like there has to be an easy solution that I'm not seeing.

```
def get_next_c_type(row):
    return df.loc[(df['id'] == row['id']) & (df['rank'] == row['rank'] + 1),'c_type']

df['c_end'] = df.apply(get_next_c_type, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['C_End'] = df.sort_values('Rank').groupby('ID')['C_Type'].transform('shift',-1)
```

Or as @W-B suggest:

```
df['C_End'] = df.sort_values('Rank').groupby('ID')['C_Type'].shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
    ID  C_ID C_Type  Rank  C_End
0  123     8    New     1  Renew
1  123    10  Renew     2  Renew
2  123    35  Renew     3    NaN
3  456    36    New     1   Term
4  456    40   Term     2    NaN
5  789     7    New     1    NaN
```

Comment: Why not just `df.groupby('ID').C_Type.shift(-1)
`

Comment: I think this does not satisfy `ID = ID and Rank = Rank+1`

Comment: @W-B I do think we should include the sort_values by rank just to ensure the condition of getting the C_Type for the next rank.  However, `df.sort_values('Rank').groupby('ID')['C_Type'].shift(-1)` will work also. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
dfs = df.shift(-1)
m1 = df.ID == dfs.ID
m2 = df.Rank + 1 == dfs.Rank
df.loc[:, 'C_End'] = np.where(m1 & m2, dfs.C_Type, None)

   ID    C_ID C_Type  Rank C_End
0  123     8    New     1  Renew
1  123    10  Renew     2  Renew
2  123    35  Renew     3   None
3  456    36    New     1   Term
4  456    40   Term     2   None
5  789     7    New     1   None
```